# Overriding pseudo styles in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, progressive-enhancement, graceful-degradation

How can I overwrite the CSS below with jQuery?

(The animations aren't being run and it's just an instantaneous switch.)

```
menu span ul {display: none;}
menu span:hover ul {display: block;}

$('#menu span').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#menu span ul').slideDown('fast');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#menu span ul').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick for graceful degredation is to not have to override the styles, like this:

```
<noscript>
  <style type="text/css">#menu span:hover ul {display: block;}</style>
</noscript>
```

Of have a linked stylesheet the same way with all of these for-non-JS-user styles.

---

Or, do it via a class you apply to `#menu` that you can remove so the rules no longer match, like this:

```
#menu span ul {display: none;}
#menu.noJS span:hover ul {display: block;}
```

And in your script just remove that class:

```
$("#menu").removeClass("noJS");
```

---

As a side note, you can slim down your code using [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) like this:

```
$('#menu span').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not seeing the animation because your css is overriding it.

Remove

```
menu span:hover ul {display: block;}
```

I wouldn't bother trying to override the css to accommodate browsers that don't have js enabled.  The number is so small that it isn't worth consideration.